# pandas series.str.sum automatically ignore illegal data

Tags: pandas

data

```
data = [
    {"content": "1", "title": "appstore", "info": "", "time": 1578877014},
    {"content": "2", "title": "app", "info": "", "time": 1579877014},
    {"content": "3", "title": "a", "info": "", "time": 1582877014},
    {"content": "12", "title": "jack", "info": "", "time": 1582876014},
    {"content": "aa", "title": "apple", "info": "", "time": 1581877014},
    {"content": "16", "title": "banana", "info": "", "time": 1561877014},
]
```

my code

```
s = pd.Series(data)

print('-'*100)
print(s.str.get('content').sum())
```

I also think this is crazy, but the data does have dirty data.
i hope data

```
1+2+3+12+16=36
## calc sum automatically ignore illegal data
{"content": "aa", "title": "apple", "info": "", "time": 1581877014}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for replace bad values to `NaN`s and also convert strings numbers to numeric, so output is:

```
print(pd.to_numeric(s.str.get('content'), errors='coerce').sum())
34.0
```

Comment: You are too skilled with pandas，thanks you very much

Comment: You can also make a DF directly from a list of dict, i.e. `pd.to_numeric(pd.DataFrame(data)['content'], errors='coerce').sum())`

Comment: @OlegO - Agree, but because answered more answer of this user `Series` is requirement for OP.